# Compare each row of a table to another table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is what I have.

I have two tables, I need to find the value in `table 1` that does exist in `table 2`.

```
Table 1
----------    
John-1
John-2
John-3
John-4
Nancy-1
Nancy-2
Nancy-33
Nancy-4
```

and

```
Table 2
--------
Nancy-33
```

I need to find out if `Nancy-33` exists in `Table2` then skip all the other values of `nancy` and display only all the values of `JOHN`

Thanks
George

Comment: [Intersect](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-except-and-intersect-operators-in-sql-server/)?

Comment: please post the desired result of the query, so we can understand what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match on the name portion and then override where there is exact match you can do it with some ugly string splitting:

```
-- t-sql
SELECT a.name
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t1.name
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
) b ON a.name = b.name
  OR SUBSTRING(a.name, 1, CHARINDEX('-', a.name)) <> SUBSTRING(b.name, 1, CHARINDEX('-',     b.name))
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, and your suggestions help me to find the solution, here is what I did followed what Eric suggested but I used LEFT JOIN instead of INNEr join, and that fixed my issue.